# What is the most efficient way of deleting a large number of named cells?

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I have about 110 named cells , which I regularly delete using vba. The way I have been doing this is simply with:

```
NamedCell_1 = ""

NamedCell_2 = ""

NamedCell_3 = ""
```

and so on..

Is there a faster way to have this process? Each named cell has to be called by their name when deleting for particular reasons, rows/cell numbers cannot be referenced. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: You can make another named range which consists of all the other named ranges and just assign nothing to that named range

Comment: If you are just to delete the names (not the Range it refers to, do something like `Thisworkbook.Names("NamedCell_1").Delete`. If to clear contents of the Range it's referring, `Thisworkbook.Names("NamedCell_1").RefersToRange.ClearContents`

Comment: Set Calculate to Manual before the delete; then restore previous setting when done.

Answer (score 2):

I did a few google searches, and I thought the fastest way out there was:

```
On Error Resume Next

   For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        Range(nm).value = ""
    Next nm
```

But then I experimented around and this is about 50% faster:

```
On Error Resume Next

   For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        Range(nm).ClearContents
    Next nm
```

Both solutions however are leaps and bounds faster than how I used to do it